# Decreasing reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Now, my reputation goes down everyday by -2 to -6. For example, yesterday I was 702 or 704, now I am at 698. And I have no clue when it started, it has been happening for at least a week now. I remember it being around 714 on April 27th, and I made sure there is at least +2 everyday (shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/45937/jesse-p-francis?tab=reputation) - there is even a +20 in the log, which never showed up.).

Nothing unusual is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/45937/jesse-p-francis?tab=reputation) except a down voted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253786/image-and-kernel-of-the-natural-projection-from-a-group-to-its-quotient-by-a-nor/1253814#1253814), can that be the reason?

Also, the (+XYZ) near reputation in new user profile is updated correctly.

Comment: It is possible that the posts that you've edited have been deleted. I can't say for sure. There should be a checkbox at the bottom "show removed posts", try to check that and see what happens.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, since April 27, I have gained at least (+)30, and lost more than (-)40, even if its just post edits, that would mean deletion of ~20posts.

Comment: Also, will downvoted (for reason unknown) answer cause recurring reputation loss?

Comment: (1) Many posts get deleted all the time. (2) No. Unless it is downvoted several times.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, (1), I agree, but I doubt that's the reason. And why gradual loss, -2 to -4 everyday for more than a week? Also, answers/questions last week were not deleted, and also, the last +20 was never reflected on reputation!

Comment: Those as speculations on my side. I don't know. You can ask a moderator to look into that, either by lurking in the chatroom of the Mods' Office, or by raising a flag on one of your posts. I don't have access to the information you seek.

Comment: BTW using this link you can access your reputation breakdown in text form: http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation
If you save the content from there from time to time, by comparing the files you can find out where is the missing reputation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These questions, to which you've posted suggested edits, were deleted in the past three days:

1. [How to prove equality between the set $\sin(2\pi*k*m/n)$ $k=0,..,n-1$ and the set $\sin(2\pi*k/n)$ $k=0,..,n-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246334) Here is the [suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/395666)
2. [Given that $f(x)=\frac{5}{x-8}$ and $g(x)=\frac{9}{x+9}$, find](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1249485) Here is the [suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/396896)
3. [dealing with quadratic equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246552) Here is the [suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/395744)
4. [Show that the solution of the Cauchy problem $x(t,t_0,x_0)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$ is definite for all $t\geq t_0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1251283) Here is the [suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/397715)
5. [Can somebody please help me with this cumulative distribution function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1251262) Here is the [suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/397709)

There are more questions deleted longer ago, as well.

Only users with 10K of reputation or more can see these deleted questions.

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154949/why-are-suggested-edits-for-deleted-questions-and-answers-visible-even-with-less), suggested edits should still be visible even if the post is deleted - however I do not know how to find a link to the suggested edit, even if I have a link to a deleted question. But I suppose that also [review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/395666) of the post will be visible. (Maybe some user with less than 10k can confirm.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Confirmed!

Comment: @MartinSleziak Click the "post history"/"revisions" link, for instance, to go to [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1251262/revisions).  Since the header for Jesse's edit says "edit approved Apr 25 ...", we know it was a suggested revision and not one made with edit privileges.

Comment: I have added the links to the suggested edits.